# Intuitive explanation of order of distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

**Definition**. We say that $T\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ has $\textbf{order}$ $m$ if $m$ is the minimum integer for which there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $$|\langle T,f\rangle_{\mathcal{D}'\leftrightarrow\mathcal{D}}|\leq C\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\|D^\alpha f\|_{\sup(\Omega)}\right),\quad\forall f\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$$ If a distribution does not have order $m$ for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then it has infinite order.

I understand the definition, however, not sure what this means in more intuitive sense. I see the right-hand side is somewhat semi-norm on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, so when the order of the distribution is higher, then it seems like the distribution is "wilder" in some sense. I will appreciate it if someone can help me to understand the motivation behind of defining the order of distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitive, but imprecise:
The order of a distribution $u$ is the highest order of derivative of the test function $\varphi$ that the value $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ depends on.

An easy case: the order of $\partial^\alpha \delta$ is $|\alpha|$.

Comment: Maybe I should have specified the question further. Indeed this is an easy interpretation, but still, the order of $u$ depends on the test function space. I wonder what "order" can be thought of if the given distribution is a measure or a function (say, in $L^1$)?

Comment: @JingeonAn For measures and $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions the order is $0$.